# Insert array batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to insert an array with array like below format, how to do this, i've try insert batch also, but it doesn't work.

```
 array(4) {
  ["notification_title"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(35) "Hello! We have a good news for you."
    [1]=>
    string(35) "Hello! We have a good news for you."
  }
  ["notification_message"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(81) "Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate."
    [1]=>
    string(95) "Saat ini Anda sudah dapat memilih maksimal 3 (tiga) tipe iklan untuk dipasang pada mobil Anda. "
  }
  ["notification_type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["notification_language"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

i've try this, but it doesn't work

```
public function save($data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $data);   
}
```

Error Message

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
    <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1) VALUES ('Hello! We have a good news for you.','Hello! We have a good news ' at line 1</p><p>INSERT INTO `ads_notification` (0, 1) VALUES ('Hello! We have a good news for you.','Hello! We have a good news for you.'), ('Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate.','Saat ini Anda sudah dapat memilih maksimal 3 (tiga) tipe iklan untuk dipasang pada mobil Anda. '), ('1','1'), ('1','2')</p><p>Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/movads/application/models/ModelNotifications.php</p><p>Line Number: 127</p>  </div>
```

This one is my print_r statement

--- Print_r statement ---

```
    Array
(
    [notification_title] => Array
    (
        [0] => Keep your weekly minimum distance well monitor.
        [1] => Keep your weekly minimum distance well monitor.
    )
[notification_message] => Array
    (
        [0] => We found out that your driving is below weekly minimum distance. Keep driving safely and increase your driving distance to meet the minimum requirements.
        [1] => Anda masih belum memenuhi target jarak minimum mingguan. Tetap menyetir dengan aman dan tingkatkan jarak mingguan Anda. Tetap semangat!
    )

[notification_type] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

[notification_language] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

    )
```

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: hi @Swolschblauw no, there is no error messages, but i want to insert with that array format, it seems different with the documentations from CI

Comment: hi @Swolschblauw update on above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$post_array = array(
    "notification_title"=>array("Hello! We have a good news for you.","Hello! We have a good news for you."),
    "notification_message"=>array("Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate.","Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate."),
    "notification_type"=>array('1','1'),
    "notification_language"=>array('1','1')
    );
$data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($post_array as $key=>$val) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($val as $k=>$v) {
        $data[$i][$key] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

so you will get array like below and you can use it with insert batch

```
$data = array(
    array(
       'notification_title'=> 'Hello! We have a good news for you',
       'notification_message'=> 'Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate.',
       'notification_type'=>'1',
       'notification_language'=>'1'
    ),
    array(
       'notification_title'=> 'Hello! We have a good news for you',
       'notification_message'=> 'Now you can choose up to three types of advertisers that you wish to collaborate.',
       'notification_type'=>'1',
       'notification_language'=>'1'
    ),
);
```

**here key will be your column name of table and than**

```
$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: Hi @raj Jagani, yes, how to reformat that array to be like that format, that is my question actually.

Comment: ok I can do that can you just post your array with `print_r` statement.

Comment: i need the code to convert an array format like my questions above to your array format

Comment: @AmirRachman : I have updated the answer and please remove your print statement from answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to format your array :

```
function toBatchArray($array)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    {
        $array = array();

        foreach ($v as $value)
        {
            $array[][$k]= $value;
        }
        $result[] = $array;
    }

    return $result;
}
```